# How do I install the Non-Raspberry Pi Foundation maintained verison of Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

My boss wants me to install Raspbian Wheezy on our Raspberry Pi, but he wants the one made by the people who made Raspbian, and not the one used by the Raspberry Pi foundation as that one installs various packages that we don't want.

Also, I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, when first trying out the instructions on the website, I am getting a blank screen when putting in the files for the Raspbian installer (not Noobs)

Comment: Please post a link to the instructions that you are following.

Comment: https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianInstaller

Answer (score 2):

WRT the Foundation image, although [the Raspbian project says](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianImages):

> this image is created by the raspberry Pi foundation not the Raspbian project and as such we don't control what is in it

**They *do not* claim to maintain any image independent of this.**  I presume there is no such thing, or else there would be some link somewhere on their web site.

Keep in mind that an operating system distribution is *not* a device image.  Raspbian is an OS distribution.  Various people, including the Foundation, have taken this and created SD card images for ease of use.

Most GNU/Linux distros do not provide complete device images of this sort either; what they do provide are DVD images which can be used as "live systems" and installers.

> raspbian.org/RaspbianInstaller

Notice the options implied in the description:

> a minimal install of Raspbian to an SD card [...] An install that includes the Debian desktop environment

Obviously this won't simply install a predefined image for you, it will offer you various options based on what you want installed and what you don't -- this is what distro installers traditionally did, although most of the mainstream ones don't anymore, they come in different flavors instead.

Based on their own description and the fact that 
*this installer has been abandoned by its creators* (years ago), I wouldn't bother with it.  It will probably be much simpler and faster to start with the Foundation image then add/remove want you want.

Comment: I maintain my own image for my business (after-school tech education for kids) and I do exactly what you write in your last paragraph: Run the default Raspbian (do NOT extend the root partition), remove software (e.g. Mathematica), add software, add my own scripts, then `dd` the image back for safekeeping. I then use that disk image for deployment to my computers (actually, I make one more `dd` after I use `raspi-config` to flag the root partition for extension but before it restarts).